# How to include a link in a Webkit notification?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, html5-notifications, webkit-notifications

I am creating a Chrome extension and I am using the Webkit notifications API. I need to show a link in the notification, but the problem is that now Webkit HTML notifications are deprecated, so I only can use notifications with a simple message. I mean, one year ago I could have created a Wbkit HTML notification and include the "a" element, but now I can't.

Is there a way to show a link in a Webkit notification? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make a webkit notification a link, do this (I'm using jQuery for events just because it's easier):

```
var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
  "http://www.google.com/images/logo.png", // icon url - can be relative
  "Google", // notification title
  "is the best search engine. Click to find out more"  // notification body text
);
// Show the notification, I'm assuming notifications are supported and allowed
notification.show();

jQuery(notification).click(function(){
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can show, check this code as a reference.

#### manifest.json

Registered background page and permissions needed for notifications

```
{
    "name": "Notification with Link",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731996/how-to-include-a-link-in-a-webkit-notification",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1",
    "permissions": [
        "notifications"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

#### background.js

Created a HTML Notification

```
// create a HTML notification:
var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(
    'notification.html' // html url - can be relative
);

// Then show the notification.
notification.show();
```

#### notification.html

Added script tag to avoid CSP

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="notification.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a id="click" href="http://www.google.co.in/">Click Me</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### notification.js

Just pointed a notification for click, can be used for extending any functionality.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("Clicked");
    });
});
```

## References

- [Notification API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html)
- [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I think that createHTMLNotification is not in the specification so it might be removed from Chrome soon.

Comment: According to a post on Google+ they are removing createHTMLNotification for webpages but it will still allow it in extensions. However I am concerned about whether it will be permanent. https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/8vWo8hq4pDm