# How to include a link in the HTML5 notification?

Tags: html, webkit, notifications, html5-notifications

I would like to be able to set a link/permalink to each notification, so when user clicks on it; then he is taken to the permalink location,

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731996/how-to-include-a-link-in-a-webkit-notification) which has a solution that's a little bit different because static link is used,

I would like to, somehow:

```
var noti = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
     'http://funcook.com/img/favicon.png', 
     'HTML5 Notification', 
     'HTML5 Notification content...',
     'http://mycustom.dynamic.link.com/'    /* invented code */
)
noti.onclose = function(){ alert(':(') };
noti.onclick = function(){ 
    window.location.href = $(this).url; /* invented code */
};
noti.show();
```

Any chance? (I really don't like the static html file solution... I would like to keep this syntax)

Comment: You seem to be missing some code; you have a `} else {` that doesn't have an `if () {` in front of it.

Comment: Thanks edited it, it wasn't relevant for the question (it was requesting permissions if not granted yet)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var createNotificationWithLink = function(image, title, content, link) {
    var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(image, title, content);

    notification.onclose = function() {
        alert(':(');
    };

    notification.onclick = function() { 
        window.location.href = link;
    };

    return notification;
};
```

Now you can call `createNotificationWithLink` whenever you want to create a notification:

```
var noti = createNotificationWithLink(
    'http://funcook.com/img/favicon.png',
    'HTML5 Notification',
    'HTML5 Notification content...',
    'http://mycustom.dynamic.link.com/'
);

noti.show();
```

You can also move `noti.show();` into the `createNotificationWithLink` function if you like (`notification.show();`). I don't know if you want the notification to be shown automatically when you create it...

Answer (score 5):

You can pass a `data` property that you can read from within the `onclick` event handler as `e.target.data`.

```
var notification = new window.Notification("Hello!",
{
    body: "Hello world!",
    data: "https://www.example.com/?id=" + 123
});

notification.onclick = function(e) {
    window.location.href = e.target.data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
noti.onclick = function() {
    window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
};
```

More on how to use window.open: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp4

HTML5 Notification Resource: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/ (If this doesn't answer you're question)

For Each one you could have:

```
var noti1 = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
     'http://funcook.com/img/favicon.png', 
     'HTML5 Notification', 
     'HTML5 Notification content...',

var noti2 = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
     'http://funcook.com/img/favicon.png', 
     'HTML5 Notification #2', 
     'HTML5 Notification #2 content...',
```

etc

and then

```
noti1.onclick = function() {
    window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
};
noti2.onclick = function() {
    window.open("http://www.example.com")
};
```

hope that helps :)

Comment: Not really... because the plan is to each notification to have its own url.. so the url needs to be attached to the notification

Comment: Thank your for your answer, unfortunatelly this stills too static; imagine I am delivering one notification per post and per user... how can I track the links?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the url as a property to 'noti', then call that property with `this.yourpropertyname`

example:

```
noti.myurl = 'http://stackoverflow.com';

...

noti.onclick = function(){ 
    window.location.href = this.myurl;
};
```

hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is when you have multiple notifications and they have different URLs and they all reference the same variable.

Comment: @Fred not if it's oop -- the property would be specific to the 'noti' that it was added to.  The chosen answer is essentially the same as my suggestion, but more coherent.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone, who needs to open a new browser window(tab), but does not want the parent window(tab) to be replaced **and focused** upon notification click, this code snippet will do the trick:

```
 var notification = new window.Notification("Hello!", {
   body: "Hello world!",
   data: "https://www.google.com/"
 });

 notification.onclick = function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();  //prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab, while it stays also open        
          var new_window = window.open('','_blank'); //open empty window(tab)
          new_window.location = event.target.data; //set url of newly created window(tab) and focus

        };
```

Comment: why not `var new_window = window.open(event.target.data, '_blank');` ?